# opencv stitch horizontally

Tags: opencv, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch two images with opencv. I find the features on both images and try to match them but they don't match very well.
Is there any kind of improvement that I can do in the match algorithm if I know that the images are already aligned horizontally?

I am using :
SurfFeatureDetector 
SurfFeatureExtractor 
and FlannBasedMatcher

Thank you

Comment: can you please attach the images ? and just wanted to be sure, which version of opencv are you using ? is it 2.4+ ? are you using built-in stitcher class or trying to implement your own method ?

Comment: the opencv version is 2.4.9 and I am not using the buid-in class.
I am using :
 - SurfFeatureDetector (detect features)
 - SurfFeatureExtractor (extract them)
 - FlannBasedMatcher (match features)

Comment: why don't you use the stitcher class ? is it too slow for you ? A stitching pipeline is explained here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/introduction.html, you need to estimate scales, add warps and do lots of other stuff to complete the process. If your problem is with the matcher, and you don't know whats the issue; than you need to supply the images, extracted keypoints, matcher results. "they don't match very well" lacks information.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.
The sticher class return "ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS", that is why i don't use the class